# I want to copy a fixed range of cells to a table with a changing column reference

Tags: excel, reference, copy, cell

I have a fixed cell range A1:A9 that I want to copy each day and add to a trend table using a macro. If the copy to table had no header row and was purely data you could take it's area to be say C1:M9.

When the macro would run it would copy the data in A1:A9 to C1:C9 on the first run, then D1:D9 the next day, then E1:E9 the next day etc etc.

Can anyone help me please with understanding what code I need to use?

Literally my first ever week doing VBA and a bit of a newbie.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming enthusiasts. The best way to get help here is to first try something. If you get stuck, do some research, make an attempt at fixing things yourself, and only then ask a specific question about your attempts, showing what you have tried. Questions asking for complete solutions without demonstrating research effort usually get downvoted and closed.

Answer (score 0):

The hard part is to determine that next available column for the copy/paste.  We can do this by starting with the last column in the worksheet and looping backwards towards column **A**

```
Sub Paulob()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

    For i = Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set r = Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(9, i))
        If wf.CountA(r) > 0 Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    If i < 3 Then
        N = 3
    Else
        N = i + 1
    End If

    Range("A1:A9").Copy Cells(1, N)
End Sub
```